# Uploading from csv file to create Account and Contact

Tags: apex

Hi when i am upload a csv to create Account and contact using Apex code. In the contact i need to give the acoount name which is a list. How to get accoutn id to contact.In the code i have bold the line contac.Kindly anyone tell how to resolve this.

My code:

```
accstoupload = new List<Account>();
contoupload = new List<Contact>();
opptoupload = new List<Opportunity>();
for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = inputvalues[0];

    accstoupload.add(a);
}
for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] inputconvalues = new String[]{};
    inputconvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

    Contact con = new Contact();
    con.AccountId = a.Id;
    con.Lastname = inputconvalues[1];
    con.Lastname_lead__c = inputconvalues[2];

    contoupload.add(con);
}
```

Comment: Hello Lavanya, I noticed you keep asking low quality questions could you please read the FAQ (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq) before posing any more questions.
Your questions are either not clear, overly broad, imply a basic lack of programming skills or just plain low quality. Please know that we are not a get-your-work-done-for-free community, we're just a bunch of Salesforce developers/administrators who try to help each other out with specific problems we face.

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer to your question is "don't".

Code is not always an answer. There's perfectly fine functionality for import of Accounts and Contacts, available for your end users as well as (even more powerful) for System Administrators. Go to Setup and check the help resources under "Import My Accounts & Contacts". You can even use "help & training" -> "take a training" to find a "Data Management" video tutorials!

If you really have to use Apex to do that - it all depends if you have anything unique on Account (Name? Some field marked as external id?). Roughly speaking you'd have to first insert Accounts (or better - run a select to see if there already are some of them). Once inserted/retrieved from DB you'll have their Ids that can be assigned to `Contact.AccountId` field.